# SQL formula to match all words in any order in just one statement

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I would like to have a SQL formula to match all the words in a query in any order without using multiple 'AND like' statements.

For example, the query 'cat dog' should match the following statements:
'cat and dog in a park'
'dog and cat are playing'

I found a solution in Regex:

```
WHERE query REGEXP concat('\'(?=.*',replace('cat dog',' ',')(?=.*'),')\'')
```

Note: the part after REGEXP transforms into '(?=.*cat)(?=.*dog)'

However, I get the error 'repetition-operator operand invalid from regexp'.

Could you please help to find another way to get this to work?

The query is a free field (search box) so there can be many words to match. This is why I'm not using:

```
WHERE query like '%cat%' AND query like '%dog%'
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Kevin

Comment: i really think multiple LIKE's is the way to go here..

Comment: Consider full text search:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html.

Comment: Should 'dogs and cats are playing' be matched by 'cat dog'? How about 'hotdogs for pussycat'? Do you require the number of occurrences of the individual terms in your search string to be matched exactly by the target string: 'Just a dog', 'A dog is a dog, not a cat'?

Comment: @Abecee
Ideally:
- plurals should be matched
- only entire words should be matched (so 'hotdogs for pussycat' wouldn't be a match)
- the number of occurrences of the individual terms doesn't matter

Comment: MySQL does not support lookaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, up to and including simple plural (formed by adding just an 's') could be catered for by:

```
SELECT
  query
FROM T
WHERE
  CONCAT(',', REPLACE(query, ' ', ','), ',')
  REGEXP CONCAT(',', REPLACE('cat dog', ' ', 's?,|,'), 's?,')
;
```

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5948a/1).
This, however, does just check, whether at least one of the search terms is found.

If every single search term (still including simple plural) needs to be found at least once, one could try along

```
SELECT
  query
FROM T
WHERE
  CASE (LENGTH(@search) - LENGTH(REPLACE(@search, ' ', '')))
  WHEN 0
  THEN
    (CONCAT(',', REPLACE(query, ' ', ','), ',') REGEXP CONCAT(',', @search, 's?,'))
  WHEN 1
  THEN
    (CONCAT(',', REPLACE(query, ' ', ','), ',') REGEXP
     CONCAT(',', SUBSTRING_INDEX(@search, ' ', 1), 's?,'))
    AND
    (CONCAT(',', REPLACE(query, ' ', ','), ',') REGEXP
     CONCAT(',', SUBSTRING_INDEX(@search, ' ', -1), 's?,'))
  WHEN 2
  THEN
    (CONCAT(',', REPLACE(query, ' ', ','), ',') REGEXP
     CONCAT(',', SUBSTRING_INDEX(@search, ' ', 1), 's?,'))
    AND
    (CONCAT(',', REPLACE(query, ' ', ','), ',') REGEXP
     CONCAT(',', SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@search, ' ', 2), ' ', -1), 's?,'))
    AND
    (CONCAT(',', REPLACE(query, ' ', ','), ',') REGEXP
     CONCAT(',', SUBSTRING_INDEX(@search, ' ', -1), 's?,'))
  WHEN 3
  THEN
    (CONCAT(',', REPLACE(query, ' ', ','), ',') REGEXP
     CONCAT(',', SUBSTRING_INDEX(@search, ' ', 1), 's?,'))
    AND
    (CONCAT(',', REPLACE(query, ' ', ','), ',') REGEXP
     CONCAT(',', SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@search, ' ', 2), ' ', -1), 's?,'))
    AND
    (CONCAT(',', REPLACE(query, ' ', ','), ',') REGEXP
     CONCAT(',', SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@search, ' ', 3), ' ', -1), 's?,'))
    AND
    (CONCAT(',', REPLACE(query, ' ', ','), ',') REGEXP
     CONCAT(',', SUBSTRING_INDEX(@search, ' ', -1), 's?,'))
  ELSE FALSE
  END
;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/21f62/1)

This might be feasible for a limited number of search terms. Not sure, it is really advisable / preferable compared to generating the equivalent **LIKE**, **INSTR** or even **REGEXP**.

Please comment, if and as adjustment / further detail is required.

Comment: I get the following rows as part of the results but the first one does not contain 'dog' and the second one does not contain 'cat'.

'cats and mice in a park'
'dogs and mice in a park'

All the terms should be matched (so both 'cat' and 'dog')

Comment: I asked earlier with reference to the example 'Just a dog', whether the number of occurrences does matter - which you seemed to deny... -- I guess, you want to accept more than two words to search for, right?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion with 'Just a dog'
This seems to work indeed but it would be great to have something that can support any number of words.

Comment: Even if we managed to employ CTEs for the purpose - there is a limit somewhere. Likewise, generating `LIKE` / `REGEXP` / `INSTR` will eventually hit the maximum statement length as well. So - how many search terms do you have to anticipate realistically? - And then: performance...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is you want.

```
 Hitesh> select * from test;
+-------------------------+
| name                    |
+-------------------------+
| i am the boss           |
| You will get soon       |
| Happy birthday bro      |
| the beautiful girl      |
| oyee its sunday         |
| cat and dog in a park   |
| dog and cat are playing |
| cat                     |
| dog                     |
+-------------------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Hitesh> set @a='cat';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Hitesh> set @b='dog';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Hitesh> set @var=concat(concat('((^(',@a,') .*)|(.* (',@a,') .*))'),'.*',concat('(.* (',@b,') .*)|(','.* (',@b,')$)'));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Hitesh> set @var2=concat(concat('((^(',@b,') .*)|(.* (',@b,') .*))'),'.*',concat('((.* (',@a,') .*)|(','.* (',@a,')$))'));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Hitesh> select @a, @b, @var, @var2;
+------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| @a   | @b   | @var                                                   | @var2                                                    |
+------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| cat  | dog  | ((^(cat) .*)|(.* (cat) .*)).*(.* (dog) .*)|(.* (dog)$) | ((^(dog) .*)|(.* (dog) .*)).*((.* (cat) .*)|(.* (cat)$)) |
+------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Hitesh> select * from test where (name REGEXP @var) or (name REGEXP @var2);
+-------------------------+
| name                    |
+-------------------------+
| cat and dog in a park   |
| dog and cat are playing |
+-------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This matches ANY of the terms in my query. I would like all the terms to be matched.

In your second example, none of the results would be a match. Is there a way to tweak your solution?

Comment: @Kevin ok, i was misunderstood. i am working on first one as you told

Comment: @Kevin i am confused, if cat is substring then ? ex- pcat and udog  ?  is it select or not?

Comment: @Kevin Above you said "the number of occurrences of the individual terms doesn't matter", which seemed to accept 'Just a dog' as a match for 'cat dog'. Could you, please, clarify?

Comment: No, if the search term is a substring then it shouldn't be a match.

Regarding the number of occurrences, all the terms should be matched but if they are repeated multiple times then they can be considered as just one occurrence. So: 'Just a dog' wouldn't be a match for 'cat dog' because the term cat is missing. 'Just a dog and cat' would be a match for 'cat dog dog cat'. Please let me know if it's still unclear.

Comment: @Kevin  i have edit my post check if any issues then comment

Comment: I don't think this would work as this requires to already split each word into a variable but I don't know in advance how many words the query will have.
Abecee's solution does the work but is not scalable.

Answer (score 0):

You can only get away with

```
LIKE "%one%two%"
```

if one is always before two.

if not, you really do need to use AND LIKE, because mysql regexp doesn't support positive lookahead, which is what you need to do to write a regex that does what you want.

sorry to give you the bad news.